# Is there a way to determine a Polkadot nominator's stake amount?

Tags: staking

For example, through Polkadot.js API?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```typescript
// The account of interest.
const who = "15qves7Kpm3voS6dRCo4LV4RgWJkGtcjXYmdwLjzm6rt8T3F";
// Their "staking ledger" entry -- where information about their stake is stored.
const ledger = (await api.query.staking.ledger(who)).unwrapOrDefault();
// their total stake: 
const stake = ledger.total;
```

The storage map used is [this](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage#ledgeraccountid32-optionpalletstakingstakingledger).

Note that this provides you with the "total" stake that they have bonded. If part of their stake is being unstaked, then you can query `ledger.active` to distinguish the difference.

Comment: Thank you, kianenigma! :-)